# Could my huge advantage in "potions" and "revives" ever help me win a battle?

Tags: pokemon-go

I just noticed **(1)** you can't purchase "potions" or "revives", **(2)** I have 55 and 43 respectively. By next week I'll have well over 100 of each.

How should I put all this "potion" and "revive" to use? Could it actually help me **win** a battle?

**note** My numbers could be wrong. I don't know how many revives / potions you start with. But, I do know I walk by at least 14 Pokestops every day. I've heard people complain they can't buy revive and potion.

Comment: FWIW, not being able to purchase potions, revives, and stardust is a good thing - it's what keeps this game from falling into "pay to win" territory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They help you win in the long run, when battling opposing gyms, because you can battle once, knocking down some of the gym's prestige, then revive (and use potions on) your best fighters and battle the gym again. Repeat until the gym loses enough prestige to drop to a lower level (holding fewer Pokémons for you to defeat). And repeat the whole process until the gym goes neutral, then you can take it over for your team (and you'll also want to restore any Pokémons you install into gyms up to full strength first).

So revives and potions won't help win in a *single* battle, but they are vital to fighting the multiple battles necessary to defeat a gym. Similarly, you need lots of potions (but not revives) to replenish your Pokémons for training at a friendly gym - defeating the Pokémons currently stationed there is the way you level the gym up, to hold more Pokémons, to in turn make it more unassailable.

BTW, your numbers are good, but not extraordinary - I currently have 129 revives without especially trying to collect them - in the current game, you can only use one revive for each Pokémon that has lost against a rival gym, so they can collect pretty fast.

Answer (score 4):

While you cannot use revives and potions during fights like you can in the traditional Pokémon games, you need them to heal and revive your Pokémon after fighting at a gym. Any Pokémon hurt while training/defending at a friendly gym will need to be revived and healed before being used again, and any Pokémon who faints while fighting at an another teams gym will also need to be revived and healed to full. If a Pokémon is only hurt while attacking, it will only need to be healed and not revived.

Comment: Potions & Revives matter more if you spend a lot of time fighting gyms. I barely fight at gyms and I constantly have to delete Potions & Revives because I value them less than Pokeballs, Great Balls and Razz Berries.

Comment: @Robotnik, yea, I am always deleting them too as the gyms are kind of far from me so I don't get to attack that much.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite true that you must heal your mobs before deploying them against your own team's gym for training. The Pokemon that goes up will have the highest hp, then cp. Even wounded pokemons can be sent back in for training, I managed to burn through all of mine today in one mad push once I was out of winners - just out of pure curiosity. The lowbies will be transferred sooner or later anyway so no real need to heal them all, they can be transferred when they're at 1hp for the same value.

That said, you cannot station one of yours in the gym for defense unless it is 100%.

Comment: Good point - something I should keep in mind (I knew you could use non-full-strength Pokémon, but it's a useful idea to restore as needed rather than right away, especially if they may get transferred).